# Half of the screen is black

Tags: windows-7, laptop-display

I was playing chicken invaders, suddenly the screen flashed and it made the game quit. Now the screen looks like this:

[image]

Half of the screen is black, nothing can be done from display menu, it shows "100% smaller (default)" and there's no other options.

I even restarted but didn't fix the issue.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your resolution was changed; you need to [adjust your resolution](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-your-screen-resolution) back to an appropriate size for your display. Often times a resolution will change within a game to increase the [FPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate) and provide a better overall experience.

Comment: I did it as I mentioned in the question, it's not possible to change because it's set on "smaller" and other options are inactive.

Comment: @Gigili The _Smaller_ setting does not mean you can't adjust your resolution. The inability to adjust your resolution to something else is driven by the driver. You need to adjust the screen resolution, ignore the _Smaller_ setting for now. What resolution options do you have?

Comment: Now I see what you mean, problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a driver issue. Try reinstalling the latest graphics drivers and then try to change the resolution back to the optimal resolution of your laptop. 
This is caused by games like Chicken invader which operate with non standard resolutions.